# Group by field in found document

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

The best way to explain what I want to accomplish is by example.

Let us say that I have an object with fields `name` and `color` and `transaction_id`. I want to search for documents where `name` and `color` match the specified value and that I can accomplish easily with boolean queries.
But, I do not want only documents which were found with search query. I also want transaction to which those documents belong, and that is specified with `transaction_id`. For example, if a document has been found with `transaction_id`equal to 123, I want my query to return all documents with   `transaction_id`equal to 123.

Of course, I can do that with two queries, first one to fetch all documents that match criteria, and the second one that will return all documents that have one of `transaction_id`values found in first query.
But is there any way to do it in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parent-child relation ship between transaction and your *object*. Or nest the denormalize your data to include the *object*s in the transactions.  Otherwise you'll have to do an application side join, meaning 2 queries.

Try an index mapping similar to the following, and include a `parent_id` in the *object*s.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "transaction": {},
    "object": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "transaction" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Further reading:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html